# Filter Entries by Matrix Block

Tags: entries

I have a matrix field with two block-types ("sound" and "video")

I want to get all entries that have a matrix field with a certain block-type.

At the moment I have:

```
{% set entries = craft.entries()
        .section(['events', 'sessions'])
        .orderBy('datum desc')
        .matrixField(':notempty:')
        .limit(30)
        .all() %}
```

how can i get all entries that have a "video"-block in the matrix-field?

I want to paginate the results.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This answer works in both Craft 3 and 4, and is as readable and performant as possible.

1. Query all of the matrix blocks that you care about, fetching their IDs.
2. Fetch the entries that contain those matrix block IDs.

```
{% set matrixBlockIds = craft.matrixBlocks()
    .type('video')
    .ids() %}

{% set entries = craft.entries()
    .section(['events', 'sessions'])
    .orderBy('datum desc')
    .matrixField(matrixBlockIds)
    .limit(30)
    .all() %}
```

References:
https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/matrix-blocks.html#querying-matrix-blocks
https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/matrix-fields.html#querying-elements-with-matrix-fields

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to query all matrixes in *that* `field` with *that* `type` first. With these results, you should then be able to query the entries that are `relatedTo` these results.

You'll end up with

```
{% set matrixes = craft.matrixBlocks()
    .field('matrixField')
    .type('video')
    .all() %}

{% set entries = craft.entries()
    .section(['events', 'sessions'])
    .orderBy('datum desc')
    .matrixField(':notempty:')
    .relatedTo(matrixes)
    .limit(30)
    .all() %}
```

Documentation about relations can be found [here](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/relations.html)

Comment: Thanks! Can I use this parameter in a entries query?

Comment: I totally butchered that answer, didn't I? I updated it now to code that *should* **actually** work. I hope this helps!

Comment: looks great, but I cant get it working. It just get zero results. What to do?

Comment: I tried the code without  ````.type('video')````and it is not working too. Maybe it is something with the relatedTo parameter?

Comment: And if if do ````{{ dump(matrixes) }}```` I get an object from the matrix that seems to be right. Now the question is how to work with this object in the relationship parameter for the entries query

Answer (score 1):

based on this: https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/30799/11762

I figure out a way how to do this, but maybe where is a better/cleaner way how to filter an entries query by its matrix fields?

Now I use the `id` parameter to filter the entries query:

```
{% set matrixes = craft.matrixBlocks()
    .field('matrixFieldName')
    .type('sound')
    .all() %}

{# Get entry IDs #}
{% set id = [] %}
{% for block in matrixes %}
     {% set id = id|merge([block.owner.id]) %}
{% endfor %}


{% set entries = craft.entries()
    .section(['events', 'sessions'])
    .id(id)
    .limit(30)
    .all() %}
```